# Executing a shell script within an expect script

Tags: expect

I am attempting to write an expect script, which executes/runs another shell script. This shell script configures an emulator, so the expect script is intended to automatically configure the emulator by sending back the appropriate data. However, when I wrote `exec` followed by the name of the shell script in my expect script, nothing happened. The console just sits and waits. Entering strings and whatnot does not appease the script. Failure to launch. DOA... I read from other posts that using exec is not a good fit when interacting with the subprogram is necessary.

Any advice for how I can execute the shell script within the expect script then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with the shell script, you need to `spawn` it, then `expect` to see patterns and `send` responses.

If you're brand new to expect, check out the book "Exploring Expect" by the author of expect Don Libes.